# How I can set 'attr_accessible' in order to NOT allow access to ANY of the fields FOR a model using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If in a model file I have just this code:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

what this means? All attributes related to the model are accessible or not?

How I can set 'attr_accessible' in order to *not* allow access to *any* of the fields *for* that model?

Comment: You also asked "All attributes related to the model are accessible or not?" -- by default all fields are accessible for mass-assignment

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just set:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible #none
end
```

Like Pan Thomakos said (attr_accessible is the array of parameters that can be mass-ret. So if you send in no symbols, then no parameters will be accessible.

[This ticket was useful](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/9631)

Comment: This is definitely the simplest and best approach. Conversely you could set `'attr_protected :each, :one, :of, :your, :attributes`

Comment: For future overflowers --- this is valid for Rails 3.2... in Rails 4, you'll handle this using strong_parameters https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Answer (score 11):

By default the attributes are all attr_accessible (which means they can be set my mass-assignment).

- attr_accessible - only this list of attributes can be set by mass-assignment (white-listing).
- attr_protected - these attributes cannot be set by mass-assignment (black-listing).
- attr_readonly - these attributes cannot be set except for when the record is created.

To disable mass-assignment entirely, use something like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:attr_accessible, nil)
```

This command will disable mass-assignment for all active record objects, but you can specify one or more models to perform this command on if you want mass-assignment in some cases but not in others.

Comment: But how can I "'attr_protected'" all attributes for a specific model?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with Rails 3.1, the following configuration option is available to disable mass-assignment by default for all models until you explicitly call attr_accessible or attr_protected:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment and https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f3b9d3aba8cc0ffaca2da1c73c4ba96de2066760

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to be more explicit in the denial for one model:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible nil
end
```

The result is the same as `attr_accessible` with no params, but makes your intent more clear. This will reduce the likelihood that a future programmer (e.g. yourself!) will delete the line...or start adding fields to attr_accessible.

This appeases Brakeman and other vulnerability-sniffing tools.